# How to install GTK+-3.22.7 on fedora 25

Tags: gtk, fedora-25

I try to install gtk+-3.22.7.tar.gz,but after typing I am getting below error. Request help for same.

`./configure result :configure: error: Package requirements (glib-2.0 >= 2.49.4    atk >= 2.15.1    pango >= 1.37.3    cairo >= 1.14.0    cairo-gobject >= 1.14.0    gdk-pixbuf-2.0 >= 2.30.0) were not met:`

```
No package 'glib-2.0' found
No package 'atk' found
No package 'pango' found
No package 'cairo' found
No package 'cairo-gobject' found
No package 'gdk-pixbuf-2.0' found

Consider adjusting the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables BASE_DEPENDENCIES_CFLAGS
and BASE_DEPENDENCIES_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
And then I type make but result : make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.Anyone Can Help me !!!
```

Comment: Did you investigate the value of PKG_CONFIG_PATH?

Comment: You need to install the `-devel` packages for all of GTK+'s dependencies. Also doesn't Fedora 25 already come with GTK+ 3.22 in its repo?

Comment: GTK+-3.22 is nothing its repo

Comment: Jeroen Heier, I didn't do only type ./configure for install but not success

Comment: there is solution other please

Comment: What is the version of Gtk+ in Fedora 25? Do you really need Gtk+-3.22?

Comment: Yes, I try to make GUI Program with C language

Comment: Hi,Jeet.Do you know, how to create GUI Program with C language? I use fedora 25 OS

Answer (score 9):

To search:

```
$ dnf search gtk3*
```

To install:

```
$ sudo dnf install gtk3-devel
```

Answer (score 6):

Fedora 25 already provides GTK+ 3.22.2, which I believe should be more than enough for what you're trying to do. Just install the `-devel` package for GTK+ 3: `gtk3-devel-3.22.2` using the [DNF package manager](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/DNF?rd=Dnf).

See also this [Fedora developper guideline for GTK+](https://developer.fedoraproject.org/tech/languages/c/gtk.html).

Comment: I have tried dnf install gtk3-devel-3.22.2 but getting error :Repository InstallMedia has no mirror or baseurl set.
Error: Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'fedora'

Comment: Then look for help on how to configure a distribution and install a package. The best you can do is ask on your distribution's forums.

Answer (score 2):

Just run this command:

```bash
sudo dnf install gtk3-devel
```